# jqgrid, help adding , edditing, and deleting rows

Tags: jqgrid

hello i trying for two weeks that my jqgrid works without success. i dont know much about this lenguaje. i make that the grid bring me the data from de database but  every time that i edit or add a new row the change is no applie to the database only change in the screen. then i refresh the page the chage desappears. help!!!!

---

this is the datos.js

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    url:'conec.php',
datatype: "json",
colNames:['id','name', 'record_id', 'created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'],
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:80,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'record_id',index:'record_id', width:90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
    {name:'created_at',index:'created_at', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'updated_at',index:'updated_at', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'deleted_at',index:'deleted_at', width:60,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    ],
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#gridpager',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"Navigator Example",
editurl:"editurl.php",
height:210});
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',
{}, //options
{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // edit options
{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // add options
{reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // del options
{} // search options
);
```

---

this is the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-      1.8.6.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style type="text">
    html, body {
    margin: 0;          /* Remove body margin/padding */
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;   /* Remove scroll bars on browser window */
    font-size: 75%;
    }
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>
 <table id="grid_id"></table>
 <div id="gridpager"></div>
</body>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="datos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

---

this is the conec.php (the conection)

```
<?php
 include_once 'lib.php';

 $conexion= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysql_select_db("taskmaker", $conexion);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, record_id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at       FROM Team", $conexion);

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
$responce->rows[$i]   ['cell']=array($row[id],$row[name],$row[record_id],$row[created_at],$row[updated_at],$row[d  eleted_at]);
$i++;
}
echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

---

this is the lib.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$database = "taskmaker";
?>
```

thats all.

Comment: You don't included the ode of the `editurl.php` which is the most important part in case of modifications on the server side. Moreover you should include a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp for example) at least in the form `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid supports different ways to edit the contain of the grids: [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing), [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing), [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing). Your current code use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing). You can see the editing live in [the demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Choose on the left tree part the item "Live Data Manipulation" and then "Navigator". See also "Row Editing" / "Input types" to understand how [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) can look like.

After the user finish the row editing and press "Submit" button the information about the row added/changed/deleted will be posted to the URL defined by the `editurl` parameter of the jqGrid (editurl.php in your case). Together with the row data, as the additional parameter, will be posted `oper` which will be `"add"`, `"edit"` or `"del"` string and the `id` which can be `"_empty"` in case of adding a new row. In case of adding of the new row your server code have to return the `id` of the new added row. It is very helpful to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what will be send to and returned from the server during the row editing.

So the implementation of the `editurl.php` is what you miss in your server code.